# How can I fix my migrations? ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version and db:migrate:status are wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I did a mixture of `rake db:migrate` and doing a `pg_restore` (Postgres restore from backup).

This got my db out of sync with `db:migrate:status`. There are columns in my db ahead of where `ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version` so when I try to migrate I get `PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "foo_bar" already exists.`

How can I reconcile this?

Comment: do all the tables/changes exist in your database that are covered in your migrations?  and it is just the version in your schema_migrations table is out of sync?  you can just update the value in that table to match the last migration that is valid, and you should be all set.

Comment: @Doon Sadly not. My migration version is behind my DB which is behind my last migration file. I think I found the migration file that my DB is actually on, and changed it in schema.rb, but still no luck. I think rake is pulling the ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version, not the version from schema.rb

Comment: just change it in the database directly.  is insert the last that has run into the schema_migrations table.  or you can add all of the timestamps (first part of migration file name up to the first _ ) into that table, up to and and including the last one that run.   Schema.rb is only used on schema load, migrations use the database directly

Comment: @Doon What's the model name for this? I see it queries a schema_migrations table, but there's no SchemaMigration or ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration class. What should I run in my console to update it. It's currently 4 migrations behind where my DB is

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `psql` client and do it from the command line.  An easy way to get to it is to use `./bin/rails dbconsole`

then you can just use sql to insert the values directly.

```
insert into schema_migrations(version) values ('20150508142945');
insert into schema_migrations(version) values ('20150508172938');
```

changing the values to match your environment.